# 14.04 upgrade is hanging

Tags: 14.04, upgrade

I installed Ubuntu yesterday. Today when the system prompted me to update to version 14.04, I agreed to it.

Now, I have the Distribution Update window open, but it is hanging while "`preparing libc6`"

The system monitor won't open, neither will the command line.

How can I exit the update or make it continue it so that my computer stays safe?

I have an Acer Chromebook 11 and I installed Ubuntu using crouton (precise).

Comment: After waiting for hours for the upgrade to untangle, I decided to press control, alt, backspace. That seemed to do the trick and the upgrade proceeded. Now every time I start Ubuntu, an error needs to be reported, but it starts!